# joining two collections in C# or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, collections

I have two objects of "pseudotype" Hash(int key, list values) that I need to combine into one based on the key. For example,

```
[{1, {a, b, c}},
 {2, {apple, pear}},
 {3, {blue, red}}]
```

and

```
[{2, {tomato}},
 {3, {pink, red}},
 {4, {x, y, z}}]
```

The result that I need is:

```
[{1, {a, b, c}},
 {2, {apple, pear, tomato}},
 {3, {blue, red, pink, red}},
 {4, {x, y, z}}]
```

(JSON-like format is for readability)

I can do it on the server (C#) or on the client (Javascript/Angular). Is there an aggregate type in C# that has a method that would do that? Or maybe some masterful LINQ expression that does the same?

Or the best way is to have them as `Hashtable<int, List<object>>`, and join them "manually"?

UPDATE: Based on the answer below, this is a better way to ask the question:

```
        Dictionary<int, string[]> Dict1 = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
        Dict1.Add(1, new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });
        Dict1.Add(2, new string[] { "apple", "pear" });
        Dict1.Add(3, new string[] { "blue", "red" });
        Dictionary<int, string[]> Dict2 = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
        Dict2.Add(2, new string[] { "tomato" });
        Dict2.Add(3, new string[] { "pink", "red" });
        Dict2.Add(4, new string[] { "x", "y", "z" });

        foreach (var item in Dict2) {
            if (Dict1.ContainsKey(item.Key)) {
                Dict1[item.Key] = Dict1[item.Key].Concat(item.Value).ToArray();
            } else {
                Dict1.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
```

Is there some Collection type that would allow me to join two objects instead of going through the loop?

Comment: What you mean by `{a, b, c}`? Should it be an array of `[a,b,c]`? Or do you mean a has object {a: somevalue, b: somevalue, c: somevalue }

Comment: Yes, I should have put [] (I cut and pasted from `object[] x = new object[] {a, b, c}`. But I can make it either way, if there are restrictions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways on how you can achieve that, i am guessing you want to use a json file as a source file, so why not convert everything to objects and deal with them that way, which will provide more flexibility to manipulate them and perform more complication processing if needed.

Here's my draft version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

      List<JsonModel> ListJson1 = new List<JsonModel>();
      ListJson1.Add(new JsonModel(1, new List<string>(new string[] {"a", "b", "c"})));
      ListJson1.Add(new JsonModel(2, new List<string>(new string[] {"apple", "pear"})));
      ListJson1.Add(new JsonModel(3, new List<string>(new string[] {"blue", "red"})));

      List<JsonModel> ListJson2 = new List<JsonModel>();
      ListJson2.Add(new JsonModel(2, new List<string>(new string[] {"tomato"})));
      ListJson2.Add(new JsonModel(3, new List<string>(new string[] {"pink", "red"})));
      ListJson2.Add(new JsonModel(4, new List<string>(new string[] {"x", "y", "z"})));

        List<JsonModel> result = ListJson1.Concat(ListJson2)
                                .ToLookup(p => p.Index)
                                .Select(g => g.Aggregate((p1,p2) =>  
                                                         new JsonModel(p1.Index,p1.Names.Union(p2.Names)))).ToList();

        foreach(var item in result)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Index);
            foreach(var Item in item.Names)
                Console.WriteLine(Item);
        }
    }


}


public class JsonModel
    {
      public  int Index;//you can use your private set and public get here
      public  IEnumerable<string> Names;//you can use your private set and public get here

      public JsonModel(int index, IEnumerable<string> names)
      {
        Index = index;
        Names = names;
      }

    }
```

> output: 1 a b c 2 apple pear tomato 3 blue red pink 4 x y z

Check this [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jMbkC8) out

Comment: I am looking at your fiddle - it seems that the values from second dictionary are not appended... Fro example when `key=1`, the values are `apple` and `pear`; not `tomato`. Am I missing something?

Comment: GroupBy gives KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>; so the same problem just gets pushed inside GroupBy results

Comment: Awesome! Given that I never used Lookup, or Aggregate, or Union - I would never be able to come up with this on my own :)